# SQL LOWER function not working with encryption

Tags: mysql, sql, encryption, aes, querying

I have a problem with an SQL query where the LOWER function does not work when I am decrypting  with AES. This is a cut down version of the query:

```
SELECT LOWER(AES_DECRYPT(forename, 'encryptionkey')) forename
FROM tenant;
```

This will still return with capital letters in the result. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result is binary, you need to convert and specify a character set ([***sqlfiddle***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5e6af/15)):

```
SELECT LOWER(CONVERT(AES_DECRYPT(forename, 'encryptionkey') USING latin1)) forename
FROM tenant;
```

Comment: Hi Jason, thanks for your reply! That seems right although i'm getting an error "_You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM tenant LIMIT 0, 30' at line 2_"

Comment: I don't know if the character set is the problem but I have also tried converting it to utf8.

Comment: Sorted! I left the comma in after forename, a silly mistake! Thanks a lot for your help. SQLfiddle was a great representation of your answer.

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice, just copied the code from your question, glad it helped :)

Comment: Yeah, I didn't realise when I was typing it out haha. Thanks again for your help! If I could up vote you I would haha :)!